# Apply gradient color to string while drawing string using - draw(in:withAttributes:)

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to apply gradient color to string while drawing string using `draw(in:withAttributes:)` with `textattributes`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a gradient to the text of a UILabel, but not the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible. Using that property, you type in a built in color with apostrophes around it or use rgb(#,#,#).

Comment: can you provide some code with a property that you are saying about?

Comment: In the software I'm using, to change the color of a variable, this is what you would do:  variable.fill = 'blue' <-- this only works when changing the color of the variable.